# How to Add Not NULL constrain for exisitng table column?

Tags: mysql

I have table with data Now I'm trying to alter my table

I tried both ways but both show same error

```
ALTER TABLE sample MODIFY latitude  NUMERIC(10, 7) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;

ALTER TABLE sample CHANGE latitude latitude NUMERIC(10, 7) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```

> #1138 - Invalid use of NULL value

I think I have some null data for latitude column need Delete/modify those column first then only it will work or any other ways please suggest!

Comment: are there NULL values for latitude in the table, you need assign default value of 0 and then do alert

Comment: yes . Just i was updated to 0 @radar

Comment: @Tom it's working now but is there any way without update to 0

Comment: I don't think so. I think that's the only way to do it.  Default values only work on new records.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you still have null values in that column, first update them.

> UPDATE sample SET latitude = 0 WHERE latitude IS NULL;
>   
>   and then
>   
>       ALTER TABLE sample MODIFY latitude  NUMERIC(10, 7) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;